# Proving $\{(C,x): C(x) = 1 \ \ \text{and} \ \ C \ \ \text{is monotone}\}$ is P-complete

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, np-complete

I'm currently studying about circuit complexity, stumbled upon this language, trying to prove it is P-complete:

$$\{(C,x):  C(x) = 1 \ \ \text{and} \ \ C \ \ \text{is monotone}\}$$

a circuit is monotone if it has no Not Gates. i.e only AND and OR gates.
How would one reduce this problem to another known P-complete problem? Maybe the Circuit Value Problem? Or should I reduce that problem to this problem?
Thanks!